# Counting instances of a character in select lines

Tags: c++, count, conditional-statements, character, line

Currently learning c++ and I'm pretty stumped. I want to count the instances of a character in a text file - but not including lines that start with a certain character. Specifically, I'm counting instances of Gs and Cs in a text file, but not including lines that begin with "*"

Example
*metadata information
atgctaatgcaggtcagtcagtcagtcatgcg
atgcagtcagtcactgactgactgactgaata
*metadata information
atgtagcagctagtcagtcagtcagcatatat
gatcgactagctgactgacgtactgactgaat

```
char Z;
long GC=0;
string Line;

while(getline(InFile, Line)) 
{
    if(Line[0]=='*')
    {
        InFile.get(Z);
        while(InFile.get(Z))
        {
            if(Z=='G' || Z=='C' || Z=='g' || Z=='c')
            {
                ++GC;
            } 
        } 
    }
}
```

I'm able to count the instances of g and c across the entire text, but just haven't been able to limit the function to lines that do not begin in >

Answer (score 2):

My understanding of your requirements, you want to *ignore* lines starting with `'*'`.

```
while (getline(InFile, Line))
{
    if (Line[0] == '*')
    {
        continue; // ignore the line
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < Line.length(); ++i)
    {
        const char c = std::toupper(Line[i]);
        if ((c == 'G') || (c == 'C`))
        {
            ++GC;
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, if the first line character is '*', the line is ignored.
Otherwise, the *string* is searched for 'G' or 'C' characters.

Comment: This totally works. Now I have to understand how it does. Thank you so much!

Comment: @chikalala94 -- don't overthink it. Read a line; if it starts with `'*'` ignore it; if not, count the appropriate characters; repeat until done.

Answer (score 0):

```
    InFile.get(Z);
    while(InFile.get(Z))
```

You don't want those lines. At this point in your code, the whole string has already been read in `string Line;`

You probably want

```
 for(auto c: Line) // go over every char in Line
 {
```

And you probably want to fix:

```
if(Line[0] != '*')
```

because

> but not including lines that start with a certain character.

Comment: if(Line[0] != '*')

Is there anyway else I can go about reading lines that do not begin with a certain character?

Comment: @chikalala94 The easiest way is to read the line, check the first character and then either process or not process the rest of the line. It could be a little faster to get the first character, check it, and then either `getline` and process the line or `ignore` the rest of the  line and carry on to getting the first character of the next line. Either way you read the line, but with `ignore` you save the time spent *storing* the line.

Comment: Because I started writing this comment too damn long ago, in the intervening time Thomas wrote an answer that does the first option.